# Gödel's proof: What if all axioms of a formal system are Gödel sentences

Tags: logic, axioms, philosophy, incompleteness, higher-order-logic

By proof, we know that Gödel's first Theorem applies to certain formal/axiomatic system, while the unprovable statement to which Gödel refers, the so-called "*Gödel Sentence*", is designed to refer, indirectly, to itself.

Question: Let every axiom of a formal/axiomatic system be a *Gödel Sentence*, referring indirectly to itself (including the primitive case of a formal system of only one axiom) then how would this implicate Gödel's proof of his first theorem?

Comment: "By proof, we know that Gödel's first Theorem applies to any formal/axiomatic system" – this is not correct. Gödel's first incompleteness theorem applies to **first order** theories that are (1) consistent, (2) recursively enumerable, and (3) capable of interpreting Robinson arithmetic

Comment: Yes @AtticusStonestrom you are right. I changed "to any" to "to certain". Thank you.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that there is a system of the sort you want, because by requiring all axioms to be Gödel sentences, you make it difficult to interpret Robinson arithmetic. But if there is such a system, and it's consistent and r.e., then Gödel's proof applies to it. It will produce another Gödel sentence that's unprovable. If you wonder about what happens if you take *all* Gödel sentences as axioms (the converse of your actual assumption), the answer is that system would be inconsistent.

Comment: Addendum to previous comment: If you were to take *all true* Gödel sentences (i.e., the Gödel sentences of consistent theories) as axioms, then that system of axioms isn't recursively enumerable.